# Automatic storage of monthly history in the database and restore tham

Tags: database, datetime, validation, delphi, calendar

- Thanks to **Marc_s** for rephrasing my question.

- Sorry for my weak English.

  ***My question**:*
  I have patients who  come to the clinic alternately day after day, and I want to record the date of their attendance in a database as follows:

  I create a database with three tables `Patient`, `Calendar`, `Month`:
- `Patient`: Id, name, last-name, age ...
- `Calender`: Id, IdPatient, IdMonth, year
- `Month`: Id, Month, day, Ord

  **How can I distribute the days automatically and save them in the database?**

  On this figure:

  | sat | Sand | Mon | Tues | Wed | Thu | Fri |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | Day1 |  | day2 |  | day3 |  | X |
  | day4 |  | day5 |  | day6 |  | X |
  | day7 |  | day8 |  | day9 |  | X |
  | Day10 |  | Day11 |  | Day12 |  | X |
  | Day13 |  | Day14 |  | Day15 |  | X |

I use Absolute database 7.93 with Delphi 11

i need a procedure or function resolve my problem please ...

**Thank you for reading my question**

Comment: I would redesign your database first. The 'patients' table is ok, but the 'calendar' and 'months' tables should be replaced by an 'appointments' table that has the fields patient and datestamp (date + hour). Presumably you can't have two patients at the same time, so the two fields combined become the primary key. A calendar report can then be made on the basis of the 'appointments' table.

Comment: thanks for you replay , but i can have two patients at same date

Comment: Actually, having a compound primary key of patient and time means that the same patient can't have two appointments at the same time. But multiple patients at the same time can be handled.